# Python divide Fasta file

Tags: python, file, split, fasta

I have a file containing 40 000 fasta sequences (approx.). I would like to split this file into 4 files containing 10 000 fasta sequences. 
How can i do that?

feedback is appreciated.
Thanks.
jd

Comment: What have you tried? Check for instance http://biopython.org/wiki/Split_large_file

Comment: Great. Thank you. I believe that will help me.

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks for showing me in the BioPython directon. Appreciate THAT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask like you just want someone to write some code for you you'll get no answers. Instead of this try putting your code, what have you tried.

If you are new to Python visit here[input and output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to find out how to write and read files. Then you can use enumerate function [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) to read first 10.000,20.000... lines from your file and write lines into a new file.